# RabbitMQ how to return message from java consumer

Tags: java, asynchronous, rabbitmq

I'm working with RabbitMQ and Java.
I have an **executeLogin()** method, which sends a message on a queue and wait a reply on another queue: if the returned message contains true in the **isSuccess** field, I need to return **true** to the caller of the executeLogin() method, if isSuccess is false, i need to return false (not logged).
I tried this way:

```
boolean logged = false; 
Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
    @Override
    public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) throws IOException {
        String message = new String(body, "UTF-8");
        LoginConfirmation confirm = gson.fromJson(message, LoginConfirmation.class);
        channel.queueDelete(reply_to);
        System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");
        LOGGER.log(Level.FINE, gson.toJson(confirm));
        logged = confirm.isSuccess();
    }
};
channel.basicConsume(reply_to, true, consumer);
```

or this way:

```
GetResponse response = channel.basicGet(reply_to, false);
if(response == null){
    System.out.println("No message");
}else{
    byte[] body = response.getBody();
    String msg = new String(body, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(msg);
}
```

But in both ways, I can't solve my problem:
in the first way, it returns false, but it prints the message (with "isSuccess": true). In the second way, it prints "no message".

I think the problem is that basicConsume and defaultConsumer are **asynchronous**, so at the beginning it doesn't retrieve the message, but when it retrieves it, it prints it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the communication is asynchronous.

In you case, I think, the `RPC` pattern is appropriate:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-java.html

> But what if we need to run a function on a remote computer and wait
>   for the result? Well, that's a different story. This pattern is
>   commonly known as Remote Procedure Call or RPC.

Comment: Yeah, thank you, but the problem is that i haven't realized the server component, only the client.
I send a message, then i have to wait on a queue for a message, with a defined routing_key, analyze that message and return something to the caller.
Is this possible?